# Force email confirmation on StarterSite with user interface

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'd like to create a page with the possibility for an admin to force email confirmation in the startersite.

The problem is the column I'd like to modify is called "IsConfirmed" by WebMatrix. I think it's also a method. When I try to read the column information, I got this error:

`Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'string'`

Here is the part of the code:

```
var IsConfirmed = "";
var CreateDate = "";
var PasswordFailureSinceLastSuccess = "";
var LastPasswordFailureDate = "";
var UserId = "";

if(!IsPost){
    if(!Request.QueryString["UserId"].IsEmpty() && Request.QueryString["UserId"].IsInt()) {
        UserId = Request.QueryString["UserId"];
        var db = Database.Open("StarterSite");
        var dbCommand = "SELECT * FROM Webpages_Membership WHERE UserId = @0";
        var row = db.QuerySingle(dbCommand, UserId);

        if(row != null) {
            IsConfirmed = row.IsConfirmed;
            CreateDate = row.CreateDate;
            LastPasswordFailureDate = row.LastPasswordFailureDate;
            PasswordFailureSinceLastSuccess = row.PasswordFailureSinceLastSuccess;
        }
        else{
          //  Validation.AddFormError("Aucun emplacement n'a été sélectionné");
          ModelState.AddFormError("Aucun usager n'a été sélectionné");
        }
    }
    else{
        //Validation.AddFormError("Aucun emplacement n'a été sélectionné");
        ModelState.AddFormError("Aucun usager n'a été sélectionné");
    }
}
```

Please help!
=)
Sorry for my English.

It may be a bad way to do it... I just need a way to change the result of a cell in the "IsConfirmed" column to "True" instead of "False". The code above has been created with a copy of another page of the startersite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using

```
IsConfirmed = row.IsConfirmed;
```

Use

```
this.IsConfirmed = row.IsConfirmed;
```

Comment: This is what it tell me now:
Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP._Page_Admin_Users_forcemem_cshtml' does not contain a definition for 'IsConfirmed' and no extension method 'IsConfirmed' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP._Page_Admin_Users_forcemem_cshtml' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)